# How to pass dynamic parameters to a radio button change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have **multiple** `buttons` which is calling a function on `click event`. In that function I am binding `change event` of a `Radio Button` control with some dynamic parameters. I am able to bind change event to radio box control. But not able to get parameters values.

```
function ButtonClickFunction(one, two) {

    $('input[type = "radio"]').change(function (one, two) {

        console.log(one); // shows a radio button object
        console.log(two); // gives undefined
    });
}
```

What I am getting in the console is the radio button object and undefined. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but don't know What? Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:** I have multiple buttons calling the same `function`, **using the answers given** the values get doubled. I mean i am getting multiple values.

```
eg: Passing some integer as variables:
on first button click got 1,2.
and then on second button click got 1,2,3,4.
```

Comment: You can't just choose what parameters to pass into that anonymous function...it has set parameters already. Just leave those parameters out, and that handler should have access to those variables already since they're scoped to that function creating the handler.

Comment: what you exacetly want to do?

Comment: This might help: [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I want to use parameters `one and two` on Radio button's change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, to be clear, when you call `ButtonClickFunction` what it does is registering a new handler for click event, therefore when you click multiple times handlers get stacked, and executed. Hence for the first time only one handler, for second time two handlers and so on.

The trick is, just pulling out that handler registration out of the function or off the bindings before register new handler like

```
function ButtonClickFunction(one, two) 
{
    $('input[type= "radio"]').off('change').on('change', function (e) {
        console.log(one);
        console.log(two);
    });
}
```

hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You should use `on()`, and then pass the additional information in to the handler function using the second parameter:

```
$('input[type= "radio"]').on('change', { 'one': one, 'two': two }, function (e) {
    console.log(e.data.one);
    console.log(e.data.two);
});
```

That having been said, you should be able to access them in the callback, just don't pass them to it:

```
function ButtonClickFunction(one, two) 
{
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        console.log(one);
        console.log(two);
    });
}
```

Comment: @RajeshDhiman This answers to the question, but for the update:: the event handler gets registered multiple times since you call `ButtonClickFunction()` for each click therefore the values get multiplied. `on` should do the trick instead.

Comment: @code-jaff I am sorry, but What if there is a single button and I click multiple times on that only. That will also do the same thing, I mean multiple event bindings. So it is an answer but not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous function has an `event` as the first parameter by default, hence why your logging of `one` returns the object. If you want access to the `one` and `two` variables of the parent function, simply leave the parameters off the anonymous function and you'll already have access due to how they're scoped.

```
function ButtonClickFunction(one, two) {
    //EVERYTHING INSIDE THIS FUNCTION HAS ACCESS TO "ONE" AND "TWO
    //INCLUDING YOUR CHANGE EVENT
    $('input[type = "radio"]').change(function (e) {
        //you have access!
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ButtonClickFunction(one, two) {

    $('input[type = "radio"]').change(function () {

        console.log(one);
        console.log(two);
    });
}
```

As said by others, the handler functions has its predefined parameters. Please read the docs for [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Furthermore, your code shows a radio button object for `one` because the first expected parameter for that handler function is the object that changed (your radio button). `two` shows undefined because the handler expects only one or no parameters thus making the second parameter undefined.